# How to center carousel images in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a carousel with images but the images appear to the left of the screen, other than that it works perfectly. I have tried putting the images inside a div with the style:

```
margin:0 auto, width: 300px;
```

but that doesn't work. I've tried various other things, such as playing around with different classes:

```
   .x-body x-carousel-item{
margin:0 auto; width: 264px;
```

}

But it never works quite right.

```
new Ext.Carousel({
items: [
],
height:200,
dockedItems: [myapp.toolbars.vehicleInfoToolbar],
indicator: false,
```

})

Items are added to the carousel dynamically, an example item is

```
new Ext.Panel({ html: imagearray })
```

Where imagearray is a standard  tag.

Many thanks for any help on this, I've seen this problem on another forum without answer, hopefully someone here can shed some light on this one.

Comment: What do you mean 'imagearray is a standard tag'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the padding inside the carousel's body use the bodyPadding property or wrap the image tag with div and set the text-align:center for that div.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is specify a CSS class called "carouselImage", which sets "background-position: center;", and then I just specify via 'cls' attribute in the view config, or via setCls() method for the components to use that CSS class.

Comment: Let me add that if your carousel's child elements are of x-type "image" and are using mode: 'image' config, then this will not work. I am still working on finding a solution to centering after I made this change.